# Convertion of two xml tags under same tag into different columns into a table in SQL

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008

more clear question is: I have an XML like this:

```
<tag1>
<tag2>
<tag3 name="aaa">
   <tag4 name="value">6299</ns3MetaString>
</tag3>
<tag3 name="bbb">
   <tag4 name="value">123456</ns3MetaString>
</tag3>
</tag2>
<tag2>
<tag3 name="aaa">
   <tag4 name="value">123</ns3MetaString>
</tag3>
<tag3 name="bbb">
   <tag4 name="value">2344346</ns3MetaString>
</tag3>
</tag2>
</tag1>
```

I just need the output in sql as a table with

```
col1    col2
-------------
6299   123456
123    2344346
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "output in SQL"? An SQL statement fragment?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
DECLARE @xmldata XML = '<tag1>
<tag2>
<tag3 name="aaa">
   <tag4 name="value">6299</tag4>
</tag3>
<tag3 name="bbb">
   <tag4 name="value">123456</tag4>
</tag3>
</tag2>
</tag1>'

SELECT
    Col1 = @xmldata.value('(/tag1/tag2/tag3[@name="aaa"]/tag4)[1]', 'int'),
    Col2 = @xmldata.value('(/tag1/tag2/tag3[@name="bbb"]/tag4)[1]', 'int')
```

Gives me your output.